# Solving $x^2(2^x) = 1$ by hand

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Was trying to solve it but hand was able to come up with the answers -4 and -2 by plugging numbers in. Wanted to know if there's a method to obtain all solutions by hand.

Comment: You would need to know about the [Lambert W](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) function to find the final root of $x$ which is $\dfrac {2W \bigg( \frac {\ln (2)}{2}\bigg)}{\ln (2)}$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Actually there are three solutions (two negative and one positive) to this equation. You can easily find that by seeing the intersections between the graphs of $1/x^2$ and $2^x$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, you would have to use the Lambert W function to solve algebraically. However, if all you need is a decent approximation, I would suggest creating a table of values with column headers $x$ and $f(x)=(x^2)(2^x)-1$, and zero in (pun intended) on $x$-values for which $f(x)$ is close to $0$. And, if you are good with recognizing fractions in decimal form, you will notice that the one non-integer solution can be expressed as $\frac{1}{10}+\frac{2}{3}$, which is equal to $\frac{23}{30}$. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'm wondering how to specifically use the Lamber W function to get the exact integer?

Comment: @zeltath the Lambert W function is defined as the functional inverse of $y=xe^x$. So, you have to manipulate your equation so that one side is $xe^x$, then invert. The solutions are given [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28x%5E2%29%282%5Ex%29-1%3D0) in this form. By the way, the non-integer solution is not exactly $\frac{23}{30}$ but the other real solutions are integers.

Comment: Awesome thank you so much!

Comment: @zeltath if this answers your question, please consider accepting it by pressing the checkmark. And you're welcome!